# create a shell console (similar to cmd in windows, bash in unix etc.) in java

Tags: java

How can we create a shell console (similar to cmd in windows, bash in unix etc.) in java. That can take commands and respond .

We can do in JSP or thymeleaf. but those will open in browser , want some executable jar that dont open in browser rather than console.

Answer (score 0):

Libs to parse command-line args might help you, I recommend looking at these:

[args4j](http://args4j.kohsuke.org/),
[JCommander](http://jcommander.org/)